# Problme Recipients MFMessageComposeViewController

Tags: ios, mfmessagecomposeviewcontroller

I'm using the following code to send in-app sms.

```
messageController = [MFMessageComposeViewController new];

messageController.messageComposeDelegate = self;
[messageController setRecipients:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:...]];
[messageController setBody:@"1"];

[self presentViewController:messageController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Recipients not display

any suggestion to remove it?

i[image: problem with this black box]

Comment: Remove what? Your question is not clear at all.

Comment: my phone numbers is visible and not showing

Comment: @miladsh : do you meant to say "You don't want to show Recipients list"?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this may be a problem with the setting of the recipients. You may want to comment out the `[messageController setRecipients:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:...]];`and see if you can manually select recipients. If this works, then try adding the recipients back in.

The setRecipients takes an array of NSStrings. You may want to also check the format of the phone numbers passed in.

Answer (score 0):

Just add the code before opening Composer view

```
 [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:nil forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

Please, let me know if you facing issue.